# Throw in C++ triggers program message then crash

Tags: c++, windows, exception, throw

I debugged my application and the code crashes instantly upon the throw statement inside of this code:

```
try
{
    char newbuff[8];
    if(strlen(cstr) > sizeof(newbuff))
    {
         throw BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
    }
    if(strlen(cstr) == 0)
    {
         throw NO_CONTENT;
    }
    strcpy(newbuff, cstr); //Yeah yeah yeah, I know, I'm just learning
    ptr = newbuff;
}
catch(int errn)
{
     cout << "error: ";
     if(errn == BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)
     {
          cout << "storage buffer too small.\n";
          return 0;
     }
     if(errn == NO_CONTENT)
     {
          cout << "no content inside of buffer.\n";
          return 0;
     }
}
```

So, upon debugging it crashes **right on** the throw statement. Interestingly enough, the CLI (in this case, 'cmd.exe') shows this message (which was **not** put in there by me, and is either from the compiler or the OS):

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I'm leaning more towards C++ now, as I used to just program in C. As you can tell, right now I am trying to manage the try-catch exception handling system that C++ uses.

Comment: have you tried to catch the exception in the caller of the function that throws BUFFER_TO_SMALL? if you don't catch the exception the program will crash.

Comment: Yes, the catch statement is in the code, I have just not provided it. The catch follows the try. Try contains the code above.

Comment: Have you tried a catch (...) to see if the type is not matching so the catch you set up isn't catching?

Comment: The above code should work, assuming the constants are `int`'s.

Comment: I don't think anyone's answers are working; I'll try a different compiler, give me a second.

Comment: OK; it's my compiler. I just tried it again with Microsoft Visual C++ **6.0** (cough), and it compiles and executes as wanted. Thanks for the effort, fellas.

Comment: What compiler were you using before?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement looks incorrect: the name `newbuff` indicates a pointer, and the size of that will be 4 on a 32-bit system or 8 on a 64-bit system. Oh, right, after I posted that you've *edited* you code to show the definition of `newbuff` as an array. But anyway.

The `throw` can crash if there is no handler. In this case the standard does not require that the stack is rewound (local objects destroyed).

It seems that `BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` is a constant, probably an integer. You should not throw integers (unless  you really know what you're doing). Throw `std::exception` objects, e.g. `std::runtime_error`.

Edit: Your updated code shows that you're catching `int`. That means your uppercase constants are not `int`. But the advice stands anyway.

There is also a style issue, the use of ALL UPPERCASE for a constant. Don't. That's a Java-ism: in C and C++ by convention all uppercase is for macros and macros only.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Disagree about uppercase for constants.  That's a common thing in C and C++.

Comment: @AresAvatar: no it's not a common thing. See the C++ FAQ or Bjarne Stroustrup's own FAQ. Maybe you have experienced it as common in an environment of novice programmers.

Comment: Sorry Alf, but you are wrong that it isn't common, and your insulting tone does not change that fact.  I have been programming professionally for more than 25 years in many companies.  Every one used capital letters for constants in C and C++.

Comment: I use uppercase for constants all of the time. Just because Bjarne says so doesn't exactly mean the community does that! Like MSDN, that's a **huge** violator of this 'rule', http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Saustin: The things MSDN are referring to are macros, not constants. (though I myself generally use uppercase for both constants and macros)

Comment: @AresAvatar: I don't know what you find insulting, but one who has to resort to such personal argument knows he is wrong. Anyway, consider that ALL UPPERCASE is shouting, and that it greatly increases chance of name collision with macros. Even if everbody else you know prefer to crawl around, it doesn't make it an intelligent choice  --  and I mentioned the FAQs so that you can ascertain for yourself that the general community does not regard it as intelligent.

Comment: Personally, I use UPPERCASE for enums and other non-macro compile-time constants as well. I don't use it for inline functions or `const` variables. It's all a matter of personal preference to an extent though.

Comment: @Alf: Calling the places I've worked "novice programmers" is insulting.  I wasn't using it as part of my argument -- you were.

Comment: @Saustin: That is because they are macros.

Comment: @AresAvatar: Totally agree with Alf here. Using uppercase identifiers for anything but macros is `NOT` common. In fact because macros do not obey scope boundaries (like other identifiers) makes the code really hard to use/integrate with other code (and thus very fragile). This has basically been a staple since the early days of C.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that newbuff don't have space for NULL terminator. you should resize newbuff[8] to newbuff[9].